# Bar Code Scanner App. Multiple Handlers On a Single Activity

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I have a bar code scanner app that has the following layout...

```
     <Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/scanner"
    android:id="@+id/scan_barcode1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:onClick="openScanner1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/scan_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan_barcode1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="@string/serial_number"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner7"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner7" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/scanner"
    android:id="@+id/scan_barcode2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="openScanner2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/scan_content2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan_barcode2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="@string/serial_number"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scan_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scan_content" />
```

I want to be able to press scan_barcode1 and recieve the serial number of the barcode in editText scan_content, Then press scan_barcode2 and recieve the serial number of that barcode in editText scan_content2. My app crashes when i press either of the two buttons.

```
  public void openScanner1 (View view) {
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator (this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    startActivityForResult(scanIntegrator, 1);

}

public void openScanner2 (View view) {
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    startActivityForResult(scanIntegrator, 2);

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null && requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        contentTxt.setText(scanContent);
    }

    else if (scanningResult!=null && requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        contentTxt2.setText(scanContent);
    }


    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Here is my logcat...

```
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {  }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1817)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1515)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4026)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3973)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
        at com.example.gamezcua.etaksytemscop.BeforeBatteryInventory.openScanner1(BeforeBatteryInventory.java:521)
```

Here is my android manifest.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/etak_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditExistingCloseOutPackage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_existing_close_out_package" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SiteInfo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_site_info" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".choice"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_choice" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NewOrExisting"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_or_existing" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NewBatteryInformation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_battery_information" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ExistingBatteryInformation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_existing_battery_information" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BatteryInstallationChecklist"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_battery_installation_checklist" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FinalInstallationChecklistBattery"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_final_installation_checklist_battery" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FinalSiteChecklist"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_final_site_checklist" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PhotoGallery"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_photo_gallery" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BeforeBatteryInventory"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_before_battery_inventory" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CompleteOnScopeWork"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_complete_on_scope_work" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".JobType"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_job_type" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AfterInventory"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_after_inventory" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Both"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_both" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

updated java file

```
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult!=null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        editText32.setText(scanContent);
    }

    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        editText33.setText(scanContent);
    }

    else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to i get my app to not crash

Comment: Is thete some activity not mentioned in your manifest file?

Comment: dont think so. I just put it up. Let me know if you find any problems

Comment: post your complete class

Comment: The entire class is 2700 lines of code

Comment: most of the code in it is irrelevant to my issue and it also exceeds the character limit. My Issue is that the the bar code isnt being retrieved and placed in the appropriate edit text. So i would Imagine it would be an issue in the onActivittyResult Method or according to log cat, in the openScanner methods

Comment: 'So i would Imagine it would be an issue in the onActivittyResult Method'. Clearly not. It is during startActivityForResult as you can see on the stack trace in the logcat. Remove onActivityResult and you will still have the same problem.

Comment: That IntentIntegrater class. Please tell a little about it. What is so special? And why is it not named in your manifest file?

Comment: So i got rid of my startActtivityForResult. This is what I had in the first place but now my issue is that it replicates the barcode in editext32 to editext 33.